# The most userfriendly way to do string substitution across whole database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, replace

Edit: The technologies used are asp.net for the CMS and MSSQL for the database.

I want to move a project from the development server to the live server. The CMS I use saves some URLs as absolute paths instead of relative, which breaks a lot of images.

The soon-to-be-broken URLs are scattered over multiple tables all across the database. Some are in specific fields (like "source" or "url") but most are just part of larger text fields (html content of the cms).

I'm now looking for an easy and fast way to "fix" the URLs before/when moving the site.

The URLs all have the same structure so it basically comes down to a search-replace, however when trying to find a simple search-replace for partial strings in SQL I was overwhelmed by code walls containing multiple loops, etc.

So my current plan is to export the whole database (like a mysqldump), load it into a text editor, do a search-replace, save, import.

This does seem like the most userfriendly / least complicated solution for that particular problem to me - However I rarely deal with SQL directly, so maybe I overlooked something? If there is a better and/or more elegant way, please enlighten me.

Comment: Fix the issue and save relative paths instead of absolute paths instead of mopping up the mess, as you'll have to repeat this everytime you deploy.

Comment: The absolute paths are created by the CMS editor, so once the site is deployed images in newly created or modified content will have a correct URL, so that's not that much of an issue for me right now (I posted in the CMS dev forum a request to get rid of absolute URLs, but no answer yet). Ideally the CMS will only deployed once, so there is only one time where I have to modify broken URLs. The question about search-replace in MSSQL also has other applications, let's say we have to change the name of one of our products; you wouldn't want to modify every mention manually in the backend, right?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may help you,

The idea here is to Loop through all columns (only character columns) in all tables and update the column using an `UPDATE` statement containing a `REPLACE` statement.

**Sql:**

```
Declare @sysTab table (id int identity(1,1),[object_id] int)
Insert into @sysTab 
Select object_id from sys.tables Where type = 'U'

Declare @ts int = 1, @te int = (Select Count(*) From sys.tables)
Declare @cs int ,@ce int,@object_id int, @sql varchar(max)

While @ts <= @te
Begin
    Set @cs = 1
    Set @object_id = (Select [object_id] From @sysTab Where id = @ts)
    Set @ce = ( Select Count(*) 
                from sys.columns C 
                join sys.types ty On C.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
                where ty.name in ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar','nchar')
                And object_id = @object_id)
        While @cs <= @ce
        Begin
            Set @sql = 'Update  A Set A.' + (Select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = @object_id) +' = replace(A.'+ (Select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = @object_id) + ',''URL'',''newURL'') From' +  (Select name from sys.tables t where t.object_id = @object_id) + 'A'
            Exec(@sql)
            Set @cs = @cs + 1
        End
    Set @ts = @ts + 1
End
```